# Como liberar acesso a PASTA ou ARQUIVO especifico usando .htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Tenho um .htaccess no meu ambiente desenvolvimento.

Agora preciso liberar um diretório do site, na verdade um arquivo PHP especifico.

Estou usando esse código no .htaccess, estou liberando várias extensões, se eu libero a extensão PHP, ele acessa o arquivo, mas não quero que todos os arquivos PHP fiquem liberados, gostaria que um em especifico ficasse liberado.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
<files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|otf|woff|svg)$">
allow from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloquear acesso aos ficheiros `.PHP`:

```
<Files *.php> 
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Autorizar um ficheiro em especifico:

```
<Files "meuFicheiro.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Mano que simplicidade, pesquisei mas encontrei outras soluções mais complexas ao qual eu não necessitava, porém o que eu precisava era exatamente isso aqui. Simples. Minha nossa porque não pensei nisso antes rsrsrsr

Comment: tenho uma dúvida quanto á isso: Se por acaso tivermos vários diretórios e subdiretórios e em alguns deles houver arquivos com esse nome meuFicheiro.php, porém eu apenas quiser liberar acesso ao ficheiro meuFicheiro.php que estiver na raiz deixando os demais bloqueados para acesso?  Como fazer?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Nesse caso, teria que existir um `.HTACCESS` nas pastas para bloquear o acesso. Na raiz não seria necessário ter o bloqueio dado que esse ficheiro é para ficar acessível.

Comment: @CarlosRocha De qualquer forma, esse "design" da organização não é o mais funcional dado obrigar a muito mais trabalho. Ideal seria uma pasta com os ficheiros autorizados e outra com ficheiros sujeitos a bloqueio.

Comment: Olha só: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/|manutencao.php$ [NC] RewriteRule .* index.php. Isso libera do redicionamento toda e qualquer página nomeada manutencao.php em todas as pastas e subpastas do sistema. Certo? O que eu preciso é liberar apenas a que está na raiz deixando bloqueada as demais!